# issues having an additional admin login

Tags: php, html

Currently I have a login which is based for a user however I would like to include code for an additional login for a admin. How would I go about implementing this without having two seperate logins?

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {


$username = $_POST['username'];


$password = $_POST['password'];

if(DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username))) {
        if(password_verify($password, DB::query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username)) [0]['password'])) {
            echo 'Logged in: ';
            header('Location: index.php');


                $cstrong = True;
                $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
                //echo $token;
                $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username',array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
                DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES(\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token),'user_id'=>$user_id));

                setcookie("PLACEME", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
                setcookie("PLACEME_", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);


        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect password';
        }
} else {
    echo 'user not registered';
}

}


?>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Student login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="logo2.png">
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-input">
                <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username"><br>

                <div class="form-input">
                    <input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"><br>

                    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"><br>
        </form>
        </div>

</body>

</html>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>





<a href="http://localhost/project_final/register.php">Register here if not a member</a>
```

Comment: in your table, have a column called user type. 1 can be for a normal user, while 2 can be for administrator. So in your login function, while you are fetching the results, check for the user type. if it is 1, you can redirect to a page or do whatever

Comment: @PhpDev before the fetch I have tried doing if($user == 0{ } however it is stating an undefined variable user?

Answer (score 0):

You could have all user types inside the same database, make sure the usernames are set to be unique and have a column called user_type or something like that. Check login regularly but make an additional step to check for user type, if an account of that type logs in, redirect or show the admin stuff. For all admin pages you should just check if your logged user is an admin.

or you can echo a script tag like so

```
 if($admin) 
     echo '<script>location.href="desiredUrl"</script>';
```

Comment: before placing the header as a location I have set if($user == 0) and then stated the header of location it should be set to. Then I have done an else which leads to a different location header. user is a field within my users table and normal users are set to 0 and admins are 1 however when I login as admin.. the page does not head to the other location and its stating undefined variable

Comment: Where do you put the header? If you put it in the middle of the script and you're not using output buffering, the header is sent before the rest of the script is done. Also, you should show that in your example, or we don't know what could be wrong. In any case, what I would do is when trying to redirect to admin page, echo a javascript tag and change location.href to your desired url.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way to do this is to just add a column in your table that holds the access level of each user.

If you want a quick and dirty way, and assuming all your usernames are unique - you can simply test which user has logged in within your PHP and set a variable:

---

*This is here as an example, however I would **strongly** advise utilising your tables properly and recording access level in your database*

---

```
if(DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', 
array(':username'=>$username))) {
        if(password_verify($password, DB::query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$username)) [0]['password'])) {
            echo 'Logged in: ';
            header('Location: index.php');


                $cstrong = True;
                $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $cstrong));
                //echo $token;
                $user_id = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username',array(':username'=>$username))[0]['id'];
                DB::query('INSERT INTO login_tokens VALUES(\'\', :token, :user_id)', array(':token'=>sha1($token),'user_id'=>$user_id));

                setcookie("PLACEME", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);
                setcookie("PLACEME_", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 3, '/', NULL, NULL, TRUE);

                // Set flag to determine if user is admin AFTER successful login
                $isAdmin = ($username == 'foo' || $username == 'bar');


        } else {
            echo 'Incorrect password';
        }
} else {
    echo 'user not registered';
}
```

Comment: I tried using access levels however this is not working and im unsure of where to insert my if statement. The field in the table is called user